# What is the name of this green 2-pole DC power connector?

Tags: connector, plug, socket

I've seen this connector crop up on several devices:

[image]

(The above image is from a [StarTech USB HUB](https://a.co/d/j0byi1X).)

If I want to buy the matching plug for this socket, what should I be searching for?

I've tried looking for "dc power connector" and "pcb connector" but these aren't finding me the matching plug.

Comment: Looks like a standard plug gable terminal block...probably 5.08mm pitch, available from a variety of manufacturers.

Comment: That's "pluggable" not "plug gable", sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a phoenix [COMBICON MSTBVA](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/phoenix-contact/1755736/260518) series part, (likely a P/N: 1755736).
A few matching parts are listed at the bottom of the linked page.

Obviously the matching part will need to be the same series with the opposite sex. There are several wire connection options to select from. Be sure to verify that the pin pitch matches what you have.

[These phoenix parts](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminal-blocks/headers-plugs-and-sockets/370?s=N4Ig7CBcoIYE5QIwA5ECYA0IYBcoGYsAHASwIDYAGAVn2sQF8Gg) are listed as matching.  Here are [some others](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/headers-plugs-and-sockets/370?s=N4IgjCBcoBw1oDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbXACYwBmcgNhAF0CAHAFyhAGVWAnASwB2AcxABfAmAAMAdgCsCEMkjps%2BIqQrU6jFu0hdegkaPEhyG5gAtCOAXwAeAAhQ4AtphyNRQA) that may match up, (but again verify pitch). Also be aware that some types use different interlocking key formats.

Answer (score 3):

I know them as pluggable terminal blocks (with 5.08 mm pitch).

See here: https://eu.mouser.com/c/connectors/terminal-blocks/pluggable-terminal-blocks/ (select pitch "5.08" and product "plugs"). For example CUI TBP01P1-508-02BE.

There are also plenty on Aliexpress when you search for "5.08 plug".

Comment: They come in other pitches as well; I've frequently used ones with 3.96 mm pitch. Definitely measure the pitch before buying.